# Adding a filter on date with different relations in Power BI

Tags: filter, powerbi

I have three tables based on year

- Lecturer table - the year represents the time the lecturer was
  recruited
- Student table - the year represents the time the student
  first registered
- Course table - the year represents the time the
  course was given

I added a year table with an updating column (based on the Today function) which calculates how many years have passed since that year.

I would like to create different visualizations, each using a slicer/filter on the updating column with a different context. For students I would like to slice according to their academic year, for lecturers I would like to slice according to seniority and for courses, I want to slice according to how recent they are.

Is there an option to define a slicer/filter that chooses the context of the relationship? I am particularly asking about filters and I prefer not to duplicate yearSinceToday column in all my tables.

sample data

| studentId | studentName | registrationYear |
| --- | --- | --- |
| s1 | John | 2022 |
| s2 | Jack | 2023 |
| s3 | Jill | 2022 |

| lecturerId | lecturerName | lecturerRecruitementYear |
| --- | --- | --- |
| l1 | Luke | 2019 |
| l2 | Leia | 2018 |
| l3 | Lando | 2022 |

| courseId | courseName | coursYear |
| --- | --- | --- |
| c1.2022 | Python | 2022 |
| c1.2023 | Python | 2023 |
| c2.2022 | Java | 2022 |

| courseId | lecturerId |
| --- | --- |
| c1.2022 | l1 |
| c1.2023 | l2 |
| c2.2022 | l3 |
| c2.2022 | l2 |

| courseId | studentId |
| --- | --- |
| c1.2022 | s1 |
| c1.2022 | s2 |
| c1.2023 | s2 |
| c1.2023 | s3 |
| c2.2022 | s3 |

| year | yearSinceToday |
| --- | --- |
| 2018 | 5 |
| 2019 | 4 |
| 2020 | 3 |
| 2021 | 2 |
| 2022 | 1 |
| 2023 | 0 |

I would like to be able to ask questions like:

- How many courses from year X there are with a lecturer with seniority at least Y?
- How many students of the academic year of at least X take each course from year Y?

and so on

Comment: Consider duplicating your date table to enable user-friendly role-playing dimensions.  See eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/relationships-active-inactive

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tried avoiding duplication, but perhaps this is unavoidable. As it says in the link, the year dimension is small. Is there any venue for suggesting new features in Power BI? Since role-playing dimensions are known to cause these issues, it may useful to be able to express theses relationships explicitly.

Comment: Yep: https://ideas.powerbi.com/